# Adding acf new field causing error with my exisitng function

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to create new field using ACF but my existing code is causing problem, Please have a look at the code first
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'makeNotePrivate', 10, 2);

```
function makeNotePrivate($data, $postarr)
{

  if((count_user_posts(get_current_user_id(), 'note') > 4) AND !$postarr['ID']) //I'm defining restriction that user not able to create more than 4 note(Note is custom post type)
  {
    die("You have reached your limit ");  
  }
  if($data['post_type'] == 'note')
  {
    $data['post_title'] = sanitize_text_field($data['post_title']);
    $data['post_content'] = sanitize_textarea_field($data['post_content']);
  }
  if($data['post_type'] = 'note' AND $data['post_status']!='trash')
  {
    $data['post_status'] = "private";
  }
  return $data;
}
```

Now Problem is that when I creating new field in Advance custom plugin than It shows "You have reached your limit". It doesn't make any sense because I've define the condition for Note type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your is checking not checking for the post type at the first condition. You can use below condition to check the post type:

```
function makeNotePrivate($data, $postarr)
{

  if((count_user_posts(get_current_user_id(), 'note') > 4) && !$postarr['ID'] && $data['post_type'] == 'note') //I'm defining restriction that user not able to create more than 4 note(Note is custom post type)
  {
    die("You have reached your limit ");  
  }
  if($data['post_type'] == 'note')
  {
    $data['post_title'] = sanitize_text_field($data['post_title']);
    $data['post_content'] = sanitize_textarea_field($data['post_content']);
  }
  if($data['post_type'] = 'note' && $data['post_status']!='trash')
  {
    $data['post_status'] = "private";
  }
  return $data;
}
```